# ASP.NET Core 2 MySQL 8.0.8-dmr Entity Framework Extensions not found

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Upgrading an ASP.NET Core Web Application to .NET Core 2.0, I'm having difficulty with MySQL extension method not found after upgrading to MySQL 8.0.8-dmr release.

MySQL Data Entity Framework Core was upgraded to 8.0.8-dmr

```
$ dotnet add package MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore --version 8.0.8-dmr
```

In my `Startup.cs`, I have:

```
using MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Extensions;
```

But in the MySQL 8.0.8-dmr release, the `Extensions` namespace is not found.

> error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Extensions' does not exist in the namespace 'MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

This is required to use MySQL, as in `ConfigureServices()`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseMySQL(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Without the extension method, this results in:

> error CS1061: 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseMySQL' and no extension method 'UseMySQL' accepting a first argument of type 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' could be found

Is there a different methodology for using MySQL in ASP.NET Core 2 Web Apps?

Comment: Did you tried if the casing changed? i.e. if there's one called `UseMysql` instead? Or if you got any nuget package restore warnings

Comment: Does `MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore 8.0.8-dmr` work on `.Net core 2`? Mine is not working. I'm getting error `...does not have an implementation`

Comment: @NEER No, it's not yet compatible with .NET Core 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed in the comments, try changing the casing, i.e. `UseMysql`. Also check for nuget package restore warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe can helps

I my testing I build a 5.5.56-MariaDB
Works with visualStudio 2017
The project is asp .net core 2
I install
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools v2.0.1
Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql v2.0.0.1
 and by default VS install
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All v2.0.3
Microsoft.NETCore.App v2.0.0
And don't forget when you type your command specify the entity framework you want use...
EntityFrameworkCore\update-database

In my DbContext:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    => optionsBuilder
        .UseMySql(@"Server=hostIp;database=dbName;uid=root;pwd=123456;");
```

Works well for me

More info on Pomelo @ https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/blob/master/README.md#getting-started